# Xamarin.forms tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms

When i am trying to use toolbar getting following error at runtime.
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Toolbar

Also I am not able to access toolbar of Android.Support.V7.Widget it gives me error
CS0234  C# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can u provide some more information about this.

Comment: This is my code in axml  <android.support.design.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" 
         android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" /> and i am getting error error at runtime. Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Toolbar

Comment: following is my code in axml  and i am getting below error at runtime. 

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Toolbar

{<android.support.design.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" 
         android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />}

Comment: This problem will likely occur when the version of your appcompat library and design support library doesn't match.

Comment: i update the nuget packages in android project.how do i update design support library

Answer (score 0):

This is my TabbedPage Layout. Try using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EDEDED"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabTextColor="#000000"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#d99a33"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#d99a33"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

And this is my ToolBar Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I want to use tablayout and toolbar. i used this layout its still giving me error Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Yes. Completely remove all your support libraries. And re-install them. And then clean and rebuild your solution. Try this.

Comment: i tried to update the support library but for xamarin.android.support.design but it gave me error that is not compatible with xamarin.forms latest version 2.3.4.247.so i degrade the xamarin.forms version its now 2.3.3.193..Now i am still facing the issue i also tried your code but still it throw error now its  Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown>